# Move rows onedit(event) to different sheets based on cell values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to run a script triggered by an onedit(event) to different sheets based on cell values for assignments. I have a dropdown list to select the investigator name and corresponding sheets with each investigator name:

```
function onEdit(event){
// assumes source data in sheet named [Pending assignment]
// target sheet of move to named [investigator]
// test column with [investigator name] is col 2 or B
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Pending assignment" && r.getColumn() == 2 && r.getValue() == "Investigator 1") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Investigator 1");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

I am able to get the code to work for only one name at a time. I have tried OR statements and combining functions but no luck (or maybe I am just writing them incorrectly). Is there a way to get this function to work to send the rows to different sheets based on the cell value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the values and what are the sheet names

Comment: I have employee names, but for example, the values from the list would be "Investigator 1, Investigator 2, Investigator 3" and the sheet names would be the same.

Comment: What are the source sheet names?

Comment: There is only one source sheet name: "Pending assignment"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const tshs = ['Investigator 1','Investigator 2','Investigator 3'];
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = tshs.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName() == "Pending assignment" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && ~idx) {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(tshs[idx]);
    let tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Perhaps this will work:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');
  const tshs = ['Investigator 1','Investigator 2','Investigator 3'];
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const idx = tshs.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName() == "Pending assignment" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && ~idx) {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName(tshs[idx]);
    let tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if(~tshs.indexOf(sh.getName()) && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == 'Completed') {
    let tsh = e.source.getSheetByName('Completed');
    let tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).moveTo(tgt);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me...unless I need to append that to what I already have? ss isn't defined in here for ss.getSheetByName(tshs[idx]), or am I missing something?

Comment: I forgot to add the event objects spreadsheet which is e.source.

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! For the second part of this project, I want to move rows from multiple sources sheets to one target sheet. So assignments are initially entered in "Pending assignment" and moved to each investigator sheets with your code, but then once they're marked as "Completed" in column 1, I want them moved to a target sheet named "Completed".

Comment: So helpful! That seems to do what I want. I will mess around a bit more and see if I run into any other issues. Thanks!